# Update progress view in custom cell in another viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my custom cell code :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ShareCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblTitle;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnCancel;

@end
```

How to  call update Progress view event  in custom cell in my view controller.Thank in advanced

Comment: you should use protocol delegate for cell progress bar updation.

Comment: i cant create event from UIProgressview in custom cell to delegate

Comment: view controller from where you want to change progress view.call delegate of your custom cell.

Comment: can you give me a snippet code ? i try but cant run

Comment: You can use NSNotificationCenter. post event when progress changed. Catch this event in cell.

Comment: ok let me try will post code.

Answer (score 2):

i think you  need the following link , and create a UIProgressView in cellforrowatindexpath method.
https://github.com/lightdesign/LDProgressView

Comment: Please give some more information like some code example. URLs might break or be removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
I made a Timer for updating progressView in Cell. you call your method when wants to Update.In viewDidLoad from you want to update progressView.

NSTimer* myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 10.0 target: self
                                                  selector: @selector(callAfterTenSecond:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
[myTimer fire];

That method Gets call.calling method of TableCell.with posting notification.
-(void) callAfterTenSecond:(NSTimer*) t
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notificationName" object:_cell];
}
while Creating Cell add observer.
TableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell addObserver];

In tableViewCell.

-(void)addObserver
{
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(somethingHappens:) name:@"notificationName" object:nil];

 }
 That method gets call when you post notification.
-(void) somethingHappens:(NSNotification*) notification
{
   _progress.progress+=0.1;
 }
```