# Update Progressview when write data in NSOutputStream

Tags: ios

How can i update progress view asynchronous with NSOutputstream when write data. I have total length and i want to update the progress view by bytesRead. What is correct way to do this. Here is my stream code :

```
-(void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode{
    switch (eventCode) {
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted: {
            //   self.nsStream = aStream;


        } break;
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable: {

            NSLog(@"NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable");
        }break;
        case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable: {

            if (self.data == nil) {
                self.data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
            }
            uint8_t *readBytes = (uint8_t *)[self.completeData mutableBytes];
            readBytes += self.byteIndex; // instance variable to move pointer
            int data_len = [self.completeData length];

            unsigned int len = ((data_len - self.byteIndex >= 1024) ?
                                1024 : (data_len-self.byteIndex));
            uint8_t buf[len];
            (void)memcpy(buf, readBytes, len);
            len = [self.outputStream write:(const uint8_t *)buf maxLength:len];
            self.byteIndex += len;
            NSLog(@"SHARE SUCCESSFULLY WITH %d ",self.byteIndex);
            break;
        } break;
        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred: {
            NSLog(@"NSStreamEventErrorOccurred");
        } break;
        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
        {
            [self.outputStream close];
            [self.outputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                                         forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

            self.outputStream = nil; // oStream is instance variable
            break;        }   break;
        default: {
            assert(NO);
        } break;
    }

}
```

and progress view on custom cell

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIndentifier = @"ShareCell";
    ShareCell *shareCell = [self.shareTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIndentifier];
    shareCell.delegate = self;

    // Progressview in here
    shareCell.progressView
    shareCell.lblTitle.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
    return shareCell;
}
```

Comment: you want to update progressview in custom cell?|

Comment: i have done this try this may help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27243597/update-progress-view-in-custom-cell-in-another-viewcontroller?noredirect=1#comment42963191_27243597

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Key-Value Observing.

First of all, make your bytesRead a property of the steam reader.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int bytesRead;
```

Then add a listener to your reader.

```
[streamreader addObserver:listener forKeyPath:@"bytesRead" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

The KeyPath is the actual name of your property "bytesRead".

Then implement this function in your listener class:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
```

Whenever your bytesRead's value changes, this method is invoked. Update your progress view in this method. You might want to tune the frequency of updating the bytesRead value, so to avoid updating the progress view too often.